# "import requests" in AWS Lambda without a layer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-requests

I've had a lambda function in Python 3.9 which is pretty simple. Just sends a post request. It has worked fine for the past few weeks.

I've deleted and remade the stack several times in CloudFormation, and have had no issues.

Randomly, today it started throwing the error

```
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'index': No module named 'requests'",
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
```

index.py is the name of the lambda function.

So I looked it up, and everyone says that 'requests' is not prepackaged into Lambda, and you need to create a layer where you manually install it into a zip etc.

How is this possible? It worked for weeks without having to create a layer, and the code was not touched.

But now 'import requests' just stops working?

There are of course other alternatives to the requests module. 'urllib' comes to mind. But this is bugging me. How is it possible that it worked for weeks, but randomly just stops being able to import this module?

Its like some kind of Mandela effect. Every single person says you need to create a venv, and package it with dependencies manually. I've never had to do that and it worked for AGES. I feel like im going crazy...

Comment: Probably you bundled request with your own code. layer is only one way of adding libraries to lambda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you possibly change the version of Python used by the function?

From [Upcoming changes to the Python SDK in AWS Lambda | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/upcoming-changes-to-the-python-sdk-in-aws-lambda/):

> In response to customer feedback, we have decided to cancel the change described in this blog post. The version of the AWS SDK included in the AWS Lambda runtimes for Python 2.7, Python 3.6 and Python 3.7 will continue to include the ‘requests’ module in Botocore. No action is required for customers using these runtimes. The Lambda runtimes for **Python 3.8 and later** do not include the ‘requests’ module. Customers using ‘requests’ with these runtimes should package the ‘requests’ module with their function code or as a Lambda layer.

Comment: OMG this is exactly it. It was 3.6, but 3.6 is deprecated for lambda now, so I just upgraded to 3.9.

I should've upgraded to 3.7 Thank you so much!